# C# Reflection - FieldInfo.GetValue get variables and values from another class

Tags: c#, reflection, getvalue

so I'm trying to add some stuff to my debug output and I'm currently trying to dynamically get the class variables and the values of it. I tried some stuff and got it working quite fast when I added the cod ein the same class like this:

```
var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance |
        BindingFlags.Static |
        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        BindingFlags.Public;

Console.WriteLine("");
foreach (var variable in typeof(TestingStuff).GetFields(bindingFlags))
{
    Debugger.Debug(Context.Player.GetUsername(), $"{variable.Name}: variable.GetValue(this)}");
}
Console.WriteLine("");
```

This outputs the following result:

```
15:47:09 [Test1] _currentTarget:
15:47:09 [Test1] _currentlyPathing: False
15:47:09 [Test1] _moveToTest:
15:47:09 [Test1] _botName: Test_ZerGo01
```

This is exactly what I want, but when I try to pass that stuff to my actual "Debugger" output I can't use `this` because it's a static method. I have no idea what I should replace the `this` with.

This is my "debugger" method:

```
public static void Error(string playerName, Exception ex, Type classType = null)
{
    ...
    if (classType != null)
    {
        var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance |
            BindingFlags.Static |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            BindingFlags.Public;

        if (classType.GetFields(bindingFlags).Length > 1)
        {
            message += DebuggerLine("Plugin Class Variables") + nL;

            foreach (var variable in classType.GetFields(bindingFlags))
            {
                message += DebuggerLine(variable.Name, variable.GetValue(???).ToString()) + nL;
            }
        }

        message += DebuggerLine() + nL;
    }
    ...
}
```

Could someone please tell me what I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass the target object instance to your `Error` method and then use that instance in place of `this`.  Note that you can get the class type from the object instance, so you don't have to pass that in.  Here is what the modified method would look like.

```
public static void Error(string playerName, Exception ex, object instance = null)
{
    ...
    if (instance != null)
    {
        var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance |
            BindingFlags.Static |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            BindingFlags.Public;

        Type classType = instance.GetType();
        if (classType.GetFields(bindingFlags).Length > 1)
        {
            message += DebuggerLine("Plugin Class Variables") + nL;

            foreach (var variable in classType.GetFields(bindingFlags))
            {
                message += DebuggerLine(variable.Name, variable.GetValue(instance).ToString()) + nL;
            }
        }

        message += DebuggerLine() + nL;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, call the method like this:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debugger.Error(Context.Player.GetUsername(), ex, this);
}
```

Comment: Well what object are you passing to it?  In the code in the top part of your question, where you said it was working exactly as you want-- what class is that in?  You need to pass that instance (`this`) to `Error`

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure if I'm passing the class the right way, but this is what I was doing: `Debugger.Error(Context.Player.GetUsername(), e, typeof(TestingStuff));`

I want to get all variables and values from `TestingStuff`.

Comment: You have a `TestingStuff` instance that has the variables, right?  So you should do: `Debugger.Error(Context.Player.GetUsername(), e, testingStuffInstance);`  If you are calling `Error` from inside the `TestingStuff` instance, then it would be: `Debugger.Error(Context.Player.GetUsername(), e, this);`

Comment: I passed the wrong object, that's why it didn't work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `null` for `static` members instead of object instance reference.

```
if ( variable.IsStatic ) 
  message += DebuggerLine(variable.Name, variable.GetValue(null).ToString()) + nL;
else
if ( instance != null )
  message += DebuggerLine(variable.Name, variable.GetValue(instance).ToString()) + nL;
else
  // Manage method call mistmatch: 
  // add an error string to the message or do nothing or what you want
```

Modify the method signature as:

```
public static void Error(string playerName,
                         Exception ex,
                         Type classType = null,
                         object instance = null)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue

Comment: When I use `null` i get this: `Non-static field requires a target.`

Comment: Have you tested `if ( variable.IsStatic )` ?

Comment: Also thanks to you, this will definitely help me in the long run.